# store data from node.js to sql database

Tags: sql-server, node.js, stored-procedures, insert

I am trying to store result data received from client side into sql database, however I am getting these errors

> 1. TypeError: request.query(...).then is not a function
> 2. TypeError: callback is not a function

I am quite new to node.js and sql database. I spent quite a bit of time to figure these but not sure where to start,,
I tried to remove .then, it works fine but still throws 2nd error. Can anyone please advice on this problem?

**node.js**

```
//Receive from Angular Server 
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.all("/*", function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
  next();
});

app.listen(1433, function () { console.log('Example app listening on port 1433!') })

var sql = require('mssql');
var config = {
  server: "",
  database: "",
  user: "",
  password: "",
  port: 
};


app.post('/ping', function (req, res) {
  res.send(res.body);
  var jsondata = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  var test = JSON.parse(jsondata);

  var values = [];
  values.push(test.GradeA, test.GradeB, test.GradeC)
  console.log(values);
  //values = [ '25', '36', '32' ] 

    var dbConn = new sql.Connection(config);
    dbConn.connect().then(function () {
      var transaction = new sql.Transaction(dbConn);

      transaction.begin().then(function () {
        var request = new sql.Request(transaction);

        request.query("INSERT INTO RMS (GradeA, GradeB, GradeC) values VALUES ? ", [values])
          .then(function () {
            transaction.commit().then(function (recordSet) {
              console.log('Rows Affected :' + request.rowsAffected);
              dbConn.close();

            }).catch(function (err) {

              console.log("Error in Transaction Commit" + err);
              dbConn.close();
            });
          }).catch(function (err) {

            console.log("Error in Transaction Begin" + err);
            dbConn.close();
          });

      }).catch(function (err) {

        console.log(err);
        dbConn.close();
      });
    }).catch(function (err) {

      console.log(err);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.query("INSERT INTO RMS (GradeA, GradeB, GradeC) values VALUES ? ", [values])` should be the line giving the error. It assumes the second parameter should be function. And when the second parameter is passed it does not return a promise and thus does not have `then` method.

`mssql` modules does not seem to support escaping in the way you are trying to do it. It support input method which can be used to inject data into query. From docs:

```
request
.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, value)
        .query('select * from mytable where id = @input_parameter'
```

Comment: I replaced the line that causes the error with request.input('input_parameter', sql.Int, values).query('INSERT INTO Test (GradeA,GradeB, GradeC) VALUES ?', [values]) and still gives me the same error,, or is there other way better than the way I am trying to do?

Comment: You are still passing the second argument `[values]`. Try this `request.input('gradea', '24').input('gradeb', '43').input('gradec', '21').query('INSERT INTO RMS (PlanW,ActualW, OrW) VALUES (@gradea, @gradeb, @gradec))`

Comment: do i have to specify each of values? can I just not pass array parameter

Comment: The documentation doesn't seem to provide a way to use an array

Comment: sry, i am quite new to node.js. When receiving JSON data from client side, can I store these JSON into sql database directly?

Comment: You should look into http://docs.sequelizejs.com. It will take care of all you SQL worries in NodeJS

Comment: would you be able to take a look at this post when you have time ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444117/bulk-insert-into-mysql-database-from-node-js?noredirect=1#comment81843679_47444117 . i am trying to bulk insert with this code but not working

Comment: https://gist.github.com/akshendra/e6c1716cca3f3e852d021918f558560c, this should work

Comment: can you please take a look at this post? I opened the another question in regards to this problem .Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47459564/bulk-insert-error-using-mssql